# Why is this php-script always returns "True" html/php

Tags: php, html, forms, function

I can't figure out why it is the function test() is allways returning True.
It should check if both inputs are equal to `$benutzer` and `$passwort`.
And only if true return `"True"`.

Thanks in advance.

```
        $user = $_POST["user"];
        $pass = $_POST["pass"];

        $benutzer = "admin";
        $passwort = "admin";

        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['select'])) {
            test();
        }

        function test() { 
            if (($benutzer == "$user") and ($passwort == "$pass")) {
                echo "
                    <p>True</p>
                ";
            }
            else {
                echo "
                    <p>False</p>
                ";
            }
        }
```

```
<div>
    <form action="password.php" method="POST">  
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="user">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass">
        <input type="submit" class="button" name="select" value="select" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is the fix.

`<?php
$user = $_POST["user"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];

$benutzer = "admin";
$passwort = "admin";

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" and isset($_POST['select'])) {
    test($benutzer,$user,$passwort,$pass);
}

function test($username,$enteredUsername,$password,$enteredPassword) { 
    if ($username == $enteredUsername && $password == $enteredPassword) {
        echo "
            <p>True</p>
        ";
    }
    else {
        echo "
            <p>False</p>
        ";
    }
}?>`

Now it works!

Comment: I had it all nicely formatted,  then someone closed it...